# How to check two arrays against each other using streams

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream, filtering

I have an array list of apps, I have a directory which will only contain jar files (I am using reflection to access these jar files in my platform). I want to loop through all of the files inside the directory, find all of the jar files and then check that they are part of the array list of verified apps and from that, build a new array list of all the ones that are verified and exist.

So far, I have this:

```
App.getAppStore()
   .stream()
   .filter(o -> {
       File[] listOfFiles = new File("C:/Temp/MyApps/").listFiles();
       Object[] foo = Arrays.stream(listOfFiles)
                            .filter(x -> x.getName().contains(o.getName()))
                            .toArray();

       return true;
}).toArray();
```

However, this is giving me everything inside of the arraylist even if they do not exist in file. Any help would be appreciated and I want to use a stream.

I would like to turn this:

```
ArrayList<Application> verifiedApps = new ArrayList<verifiedApps>();
for( Application app : App.getAppStore() ) {
    for( File verifiedApp : new File("C:/Temp/MyApps/").listFiles() ) {
        if( verifiedApp.getName().contains( app.getName() )
            verifiedApps.add( app );
    }
}
```

Into using a stream to get used to knowing how to use streams.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is that you always return `true` from `filter`.

```
File[] listOfFiles = new File("C:/Temp/MyApps/").listFiles();
Set<String> filesNames = Arrays.stream(listOfFiles)
                               .map(File::getName)
                               .collect(Collectors.toSet());
```

This could be moved outside the `filter` lambda to avoid creating a `File[]` for each app. That array of `File`s could be mapped to file names by `map(File::getName)` and collect them into a set for further lookups.

Then, you would have the following

```
List<Application> verifiedApps = 
    App.getAppStore()
       .stream()
       .filter(o -> filesNames.contains(o.getName() + ".jar"))
       .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Comment: Thank you Andrew! This worked perfectly! Would you be able to explain how this works or provide references I could look at, I couldn't find anything about using `Collectors` when I researched this. I'll mark the answer when I can!

Comment: @KDOT about collectors from Java docs: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Collectors.html and https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Collector.html

Comment: @KDOT happy to help

Comment: since `filesNames` is not a single String each time, `.contains()` looks for the absolute match when passing `o.getName()` therefor, ensure you're passing the file extension in as well: `filesNames.contains(o.getName() + ".jar")`. I come across this issue but fixed it as I saw it but just commented for future viewers.

Comment: I’d rather use `Set<String> filesNames = Files.list(Paths.get("C:/Temp/MyApps/")).map(p -> p.getFileName()+".jar") .collect(Collectors.toSet());` followed by `List<Application> verifiedApps = App.getAppStore().stream() .filter(o -> filesNames.contains(o.getName())) .collect(Collectors.toList());`